# Cross-server communication in load-balanced ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, caching, ipc, invalidation, web-farm

My ASP.NET application stores some expensive (to load) data in an application-accessible `static` field (using `System.Web.Caching.Cache` is inappropriate in this case).

My application is also load-balanced across a couple of webservers with a central SQL Server on another machine.

There are times when this cache will be invalidated. If the user submits some updated data on `Server01` then that application knows about it can will clear its local cache when it also submits the data to the database.

However, how can `Server01` notify `Server02` of this change so `Server02`'s cache will be invalidated?

I'm not aware of any built-in inter-server IPC in ASP.NET for web-farm communication, it seems that I would have to create a URI handler in the application (e.g. `http://mysite/InvalidateCache`) that would be called by the other server, but it seems a bit hackish. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a bit of a brain-fart and realized that web-servers can communicate between each other simply by sending each other requests - there is no need for a special side-channel line. I earlier call the idea hackish, but it's sound in theory.

Obviously for security purposes these requests need to go through a physical private network connection, or have cryptographically signed requests, but I really can't think of anything wrong with that approach now.

Comment: I'm in the same situation and considering the same solution. Did you try it and how did it work?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you explore a distributed cache like AppFabric. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: Ew, no, no please. It's been abandoned by Microsoft and my company is actively trying to get rid of it from our architecture. I know your post is 2 years old, so I'm not downvoting, just letting people know.